# Session variable not working in real time

Tags: php, javascript

I have a user comment system in which time of comment is displayed using UTC timestamp stored in database along with comments.

The time offset is used to set session timeoffset variable using javascript post request to get user local time.

I have done like this because user are from diffrent timezone and I cannot store time In one time zone alone so I have stored it in UTC and then displayed using timeoffset of timezone.

This system is not working in real time but working after refresh.

**comments.php**

```
<?php 
session_save_path('session/store');
session_start();
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

$.post('timeoffset.php', {timeoffset:timeoffset}, function(data){
    //alert(data);
});
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['timeoffset'])&&!empty($_SESSION['timeoffset'])){
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $timeoffset = (int)$_SESSION['timeoffset'];
}
else{
    echo 'timeoffset not set';
    exit;
}

 // here are comments displayed using while loop
 // time of comments is displayed like this
 echo gmdate("F j, Y, h:i:s a", $row['timestamp']-($timeoffset*60)); //$row['timestamp'] = UTC time stamp stored in database. e.g: 1377509788
?>
```

**timeoffset.php**

```
<?php session_save_path('session/store');
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['timeoffset'])){
    $_SESSION['timeoffset'] = (int)$_POST['timeoffset'];
    echo $_SESSION['timeoffset'];
}
?>
```

It shows `timeoffset not set` first and then after refresh it shows comments and time.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's not set. PHP is executed before the response is sent to the user and the javascript is executed. Meaning you are using jQuery post to set your session after you have tried to identify it.

Comment: @IanBrindley how to sent response first. I cannot use ajax or jquery to refresh part of time in comments. Is there any way around it.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is executed before the user gets the page displayed. Because of that, it doesn't matter if the code is in the document before or after the javascript code which is executed in the client's browser. So you have to add the time via javascript and ajax, too. The alet in your post request should give you the right result.

Comment: yes alert is giving right time offset, thing is that I cannot use ajax or jquery to refresh part of time in comments. Is there any way around it.

Comment: Um, why can't you use ajax to refresh the time on the page?

Comment: As comments and time are displayed using while loop in same page.

Comment: how does other sites that have comments displays time of comments in user local time.

Comment: Without getting more of your source code I cannot help you very much. What means they are displayed using a while loop?

Comment: like `while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ echo $row['comments'].'<br>'; echo gmdate("F j, Y, h:i:s a", $row['timestamp']-($timeoffset*60));}`

Comment: So in javascript you will have to go throw all comments using a loop, too. Another possibility would be to load the comments via ajax and pass the timeoffset as a parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to get time offset in php.